# Angular wait for observable method called in ngOnInit to finish to continue execution

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have a method called in ngOnInit which sets a boolean flag. If this flag is true, I continue with my validations. However, the flag is remaining false as the method is being called after.
How to handle it pls?

```
  ngOnInit(){
     this.hasDependent();
   
    if(this.hasAnyDependent(){
     //continue logic
   }
  } 

  hasDependent(){
   this.employeeService.hasDep(null).sub 
 scribe(
   (data) => {
     this.hasAnyDependent = data;
    }
    err => toast.error("Error")

  )

   }
```

Comment: If you are using Angular v16, you can define your boolean flag using the new signal feature. Then react to changes in the signal using a computed or effect. For older versions of Angular, you can use a Subject or BehaviorSubject for the boolean value. You can then react to emissions.

Answer (score 0):

This is an async operation - the function `hasDependent()` calls the service method `hasDep()` which returns an observable.

Because of this, when you're calling `if(this.hasAnyDependent())`, this is executed before the subscription returns, so `hasAnyDependent` hasn't been set yet.

I would suggest using RxJS `pipe()` and `tap() functions to handle the side effect of setting` hasAnyDependent` flag.

**Heres the example**:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.hasDependent().subscribe(hasDep => {
    if(hasDep) {
      // continue logic
    }
  }, 
  err => toast.error("Error"));
} 

hasDependent(): Observable<boolean>{
  return this.employeeService.hasDep(null).pipe(
    tap((data) => {
      this.hasAnyDependent = data;
    }),
    first()
  );
}
```